# linux laptop disconnected from WiFi even while android phone can connect

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I was getting a 0 byte download speed with everything constantly failing and whatnot, so I started trying to fix it.

I tried pinging google.com and got `temporary failure in name resolution`, so I tried restarting the nameserver or any of the other solutions I could find online that tackle nameserver issues, but none of it helped.

So I finally directly pinged `8.8.8.8` and got a `destination host unreachable` error, which means that my device is well and truly disconnected from the internet.

But at the same time, it can't be that the internet is actually down because my Android phone and my girlfriend's computer running the same operating system (PopOS) are able to connect to the internet just fine so I have no idea what's going on.

Are there any more things I could try? Thank you!

System info: running PopOS 22.04 on an oryxp9.

Comment: I checked on another Linux computer, this one running Manjaro, and it has precisely identical issues

Comment: what ip address do the failing computers have? what ip does the working computer have? have you tried wired connection to determine if it's a wifi issue or some other configuration issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the actual WiFi device you have. You can use `lspci` for internal ones or `lsusb` for USB devices. This may (or may not) give a clue about the problem. You may need different drivers (or it can be a different issue). The point is without additional information this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my router needed to be updated is all.